# Logging broke for authentication only

Tags: server, authentication, logging, monitoring

I currently am unable to have authentication attempts logged in /var/log/auth.log . Everything was working properly and log files were rotated as expected until last night issue.

My Ubuntu server crashed during the execution of a CRON job during the night.This morning, I rebooted the VM and regain access through SSH, and saw web apps come back online.

When checking the crontable and the monitoring of the VM I pinpointed the origin of the crash to the execution of the backup job that backs up the whole server, which for unknown reasons lead to a 100% CPU usage, which ended up crashing the server.

Now, I managed to run the backup properly and the server's services all show up green and working, but I have lost authentication logging. **Nothing appears in /var/log/auth.log since this night's crash** at 05:21.

I rebooted once more, checked rsyslog status, checked its configuration file, checked sshd_config and everything seems fine. Ownership of auth.log is properly set to syslog:adm with -rw-r----- permissions on auth.log. No problem regarding disk space nor anything I could think about.

Thank you in advance for any help or suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Authentication logging resumed at the beginning of this week when the log files got automatically rotated.